# Using a secondary DNS when lookup fails in primary?

Tags: dns

I use a VPN to connect my development machine to my school's CS dept. The development machine is Ubuntu as we do C programming in Unix. I used `vpnc` to do that. The school uses some DNS entries that only resolve on their DNS servers, i.e., internalserver.csdept.school.edu

I am normally attached to the VPN whenever booted for convenience. However I noticed the other day that when I disconnect the VPN all my DNS queries fail. This obviously means that `vpnc` set up the school's DNS to be used. However I'd rather not use their DNS all the time (tracking and privacy and whatnot). Is there a way I can restore my ISP's DNS and then if the lookup fails, have it use my school's DNS?

Answer (score 3):

vpnc hacks /etc/resolv.conf. Here are several links that deal with this issue:

1. [Ubuntu Jaunty](http://www.pythian.com/news/2931/ubuntu-904-jaunty-jackalope-vpnc-and-resolvconf/) vpnc setup
2. [CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/vpnc) vpnc setup

You might be also able to solve this problems with the [resolvconf](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2003/07/msg00438.html) package.

Answer (score -1):

Not really, because resolution through your ISP's DNS will not "fail". It will return "no result" which is not a failure.  It is technically possibly to setup a convoluted situation on your PC where you could direct various queries to different DNS servers based on what domain you're tying to lookup; but I'd highly advise against doing something like that as it's likely to cause more problems than it's worth.

Comment: Hmmm, this is troubling. (Not that I'm try to hide anything from my university *Whistles nonchalantly*). What, in Linux, handles DNS lookups? Is it possible to write a short program to wrap it that would use a regex to match "^.*\.school\.edu$" and treat it specially?

Comment: dnsmasq can be configured to resolve different domains form different servers quite easily.